# Constructing a bijection between two sets of pairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integers

I am working on a problem in a different area and the following problem appeared.

Let numbers $j,k,l \in \mathbb{N}_0$ be fixed. I need to construct a bijection between the sets

$$\{(A,B) \in \mathbb{N}_0^2: \; A \le j, \, A \le k, \, B \le l, \, B \le j+k-2A\}$$ and $$\{(C,D) \in \mathbb{N}_0^2: \; C \le j, \, C \le l, \, D \le k, \, D \le j+l-2C\}.$$

In fact, it seems that the multiset of sums is the same, so it seems likely that any natural bijection will preserve the sums. I don't have a proof that this is true though.

For example, when $j = 2, k=3, l=4$, the first set is $$\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1)\}$$ and the second is $$\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)\}.$$ In both cases adding the two entries gives one $0$, two $1$, three $2$, three $3$, two $4$.